# how to change django model admin url?

Tags: django

I just need to change

> `http://localhost:8000/admin/song_management/album/`

to

> `http://localhost:8000/admin/song-management/album/`

Note:

I am using ModelAdmin & Changed admin template completely ( ex; Used hardcoded url mostly )

Comment: Well, don't use a hard-coded URL then. Django by default does not add domain or port to the URLs it generates, so the problem simply never arises.

Comment: localhost needs a port to listen to, you cannot just run on ``http://localhost/blabla/``

Comment: @DanielRoseman The first url is working. but the requirement is do not use _ in urls .. so what should i do ?

Comment: @doniyor changed typo ..

Answer (score 2):

Django's `ModelAdmin` uses the model's [`app_label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#app-label) per default to generate the urls. The only way to bypass this would be to subclass `AdminSite` and change [the relevant parts](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L253-L258).